# Remove spines of host when using parasite axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiple-axes

I'm new to both python and stackoverflow so I hope I'm posting this right.

I'm trying to make a bar chart with scatter overlay. I followed the [demo_parasite_axes2](https://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_parasite_axes2.html) example on the matplotlib website to create a host and a parasite axis. That seems to work fine.

Now I want to remove the top and right spines of the host axis but can't seem to do it. I tried `host.spines['right'].set_visible(False)` 
but this does nothing. I also tried to change the spine colour to white by `host.spines["top"].set_color('w')` but this doesn't do anything either. 
The script for the plot is below:

Data used is a numpy.ndarray of size (5, 6):

```
print(valval)

[[  1.27225695   1.28820064   5.54155106   4.44582149   6.71393981  
    5.7292093 ]
 [ 70.75471698  79.24528302  65.30612245  81.13207547  74.52830189
    55.05617978]
 [ 22.64150943  16.98113208  27.55102041  15.09433962  19.81132075
    25.84269663]
 [  5.66037736   2.83018868   7.14285714   1.88679245   3.77358491
    11.23595506]
 [  0.           0.           0.           1.88679245   0.94339623
    3.37078652]]

print(valval.shape)
(5, 6)
```

The plotting script;

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA

N = valval.shape[1]
SD_1 = valval[1,:]
SD_2 = valval[2,:]
SD_3 = valval[3,:]
SD_4 = valval[4,:]
SD_5 = 100 - SD_1 - SD_2 - SD_3 - SD_4

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6), facecolor=[1,1,1],frameon=False)
host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)


y_axis = host.twinx()
offset = 20
new_fixed_axis = y_axis.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
y_axis.axis["right"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="right",
                                axes=y_axis,
                                offset=(offset, 0))

# Set host y axis
host.set_ylabel("Percentage")
host.axis["left"].label.set_fontsize(20)

# Set parasite y axis
y_axis.set_ylabel("nRMSE")
y_axis.axis["right"].label.set_fontsize(20)
y_axis.set_ylim(1, 10)
# Set parasite axis color
y_axis.axis["right"].label.set_color('r')
y_axis.axis["right"].line.set_color('r')
y_axis.axis["right"].major_ticks.set_color('r')
y_axis.axis["right"].major_ticklabels.set_color('r')

# Bar chart
ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.9
p1 = host.bar(ind, SD_1, width)
p2 = host.bar(ind, SD_2, width,bottom=SD_1)
p3 = host.bar(ind, SD_3, width,bottom=SD_1+SD_2)
p4 = host.bar(ind, SD_4, width,bottom=SD_1+SD_2+SD_3)
p5 = host.bar(ind, SD_5, width,bottom=SD_1+SD_2+SD_3+SD_4)

# Horizontal lines
host.axhline(68,color='k')
host.axhline(95,color='k')
host.axhline(99,color='k')

# Scatter plot
pp1, = y_axis.plot(ind, valval[0,:],'or')

# Set x axis
host.set_xlim(-0.55, 5.55)
plt.xticks(ind, ('M\_sat','M\_precip','M\_motmax','M\_shice','M\_o2',
        'M\_co2'),rotation='vertical',fontsize=25)

plt.show()
```

The output:
[image: My bar chart with scatter overlay]

What I want my plot to look like (I don't want to remove all spines, just the top and the right ones):
[image: Bar chat with no spines]

Comment: Any specific reason to use `axes_grid1.host_subplot` here? It looks like when using normal subplots instead, the attempted solution should work just fine.

Comment: That is, I would recommend starting off from [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html) instead.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you for the example. That works perfectly!

Comment: Great, maybe you want to provide your working solution based on that example as an answer, such that it is helpful for others?

Answer (score 1):

So following suggestion by ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I used normal subplots instead of `axes_grid1.host_subplot` and `host.spines['right'].set_visible(False)` works fine.

I will post the new script here in case anyone else finds it useful:

```
fig, host = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

par = host.twinx()
par.spines["right"].set_position(("axes",1.05))
par.spines["right"].set_visible(True)

# Needs to make both host.spines and par.spines invisible for the top spine
host.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
host.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
par.spines["top"].set_visible(False)

# Set host y axis
host.set_ylabel("Percentage",size=20)

# parasite y axis
par.set_ylabel("nRMSE",size=20)
par.set_ylim(1, 10)
par.yaxis.label.set_color('r')
par.tick_params(axis='y',colors='r')

# Bar chart
ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.9
p1 = host.bar(ind, SD_1, width)
p2 = host.bar(ind, SD_2, width,bottom=SD_1)
p3 = host.bar(ind, SD_3, width,bottom=SD_1+SD_2)
p4 = host.bar(ind, SD_4, width,bottom=SD_1+SD_2+SD_3)
p5 = host.bar(ind, SD_5, width,bottom=SD_1+SD_2+SD_3+SD_4)

# Horizontal lines
host.axhline(68,color='k')
host.axhline(95,color='k')
host.axhline(99,color='k')

host.set_xlim(-0.55, 5.55)
plt.show()
```

This is the result:
[No top and right spines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGP8i.png)